# How to implement conditional rendering in React Reusable Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this reusable component where I would like to pass a value through that if true: a button is returned and if the value is false: the button doesn't render.  I can't figure out how to do this using reusable components.  The boolean variable I want to use is displayButton where if it is true, then the button is rendered and if it is false then the button is not rendered.

```
const Test = ({ name, value, onClick, purchased, displayButton }) => {
  return (
    <div class="cardData">
      <h5>{name}</h5>
      <p>Cost: {value}</p>
//if display button = true, display this button, if false, button is not displayed
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={onClick}
        class="btn btn-primary"
        value={value}
        name={name}
      >
        Purchase
      </button>
      <h4>{purchased}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Any help would very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
const Test = ({ name, value, onClick, purchased, displayButton }) => {
  return (
    <div class="cardData">
      <h5>{name}</h5>
       <p>Cost: {value}</p>
      {displayButton &&
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={onClick}
          class="btn btn-primary"
          value={value}
          name={name}
        >
          Purchase
        </button>
      }
      <h4>{purchased}</h4>
    </div>
 );
};

export default Test;
```

if `displayButton` has the value of `true` it will render the button otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
const Test = ({ name, value, onClick, purchased, displayButton }) => {
  return (
    <div class="cardData">
      <h5>{name}</h5>
      <p>Cost: {value}</p>
      { displayButton && 
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={onClick}
        class="btn btn-primary"
        value={value}
        name={name}
      >
        Purchase
      </button>
      }
      <h4>{purchased}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: It would be really appreciated if you can upvote or accept my solution if it worked perfectly :)

Comment: yea I did but my reputation is too low so it doesn't publicly show that i did! The vote is still recorded though

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `ShowHide` component which can be utilized for conditional-rendering instead of having logical operators in every `JSX` where you need to conditionally render.

```js
// create a ShowHide component
const ShowHide = ({show,children} ) => show && children

//  your Test component with the button wrapped in ShowHide
const Test = ({ name, value, onClick, purchased, displayButton }) => {
  return (
    <div class="cardData card col-6 m-3">
      <h5>{name}</h5>
      <p>Cost: {value}</p>
      <ShowHide show={displayButton}>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={onClick}
          class="btn btn-primary"
          value={value}
          name={name}
        >
          Purchase
        </button>
      </ShowHide>
      <h4>{purchased}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

const root = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test name="My Card"
    value="250,000"
    onClick={() => alert('clicked')} 
    purchased="Yes!" 
    displayButton={false}
  />,
  root
)
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  

<div id="root"></div>
```

Good Luck...